# Ensuring that the value returned by Window.prompt contains only letters

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check to see if user input assigned to a variable can be checked to make sure it is a string, and not a number. I've tried using `typeof()`, but no matter what, the user input is tagged as a string, even if the user enters a number. For example:

```
var x = prompt("Enter a string of letters");
var y = typeof x;

if (y !== "string") {
    alert("You did not enter a string");
}
```

Is there something I could use that's similar to the `NaN` function, but for strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result returned from `prompt` will always be a string (or potentially the value `null`). That's what the method returns. It's important to remember that `"123"` is in fact a string, even though it's also the string representation of a number.

So, in your case, you're not really trying to determine whether it's a string; you're trying to ensure that it's not a number. More generally, you're question says "a string of letters".

This just means that you need to validate that the resulting string contains only letters, and no digits or symbols. You can do that with a simple regular expression:

```js
var x = prompt("Enter a string of letters");

if (!x || !x.match(/^[a-z]+$/i)) {
    alert("Only letters are allowed");
}
```

A few points to note here. This will not allow the blank string `""`; if you need to allow that, change the `+` (one or more quantifier) to `*` (zero or more) in the regex. You'll also have to explicitly check for `null` (by doing `x != null`) instead of using `!x`, since `""` is falsey.

This regex won't allow spaces either. You can include the space matcher in the character class to allow that.

Comment: The `!x` condition doesn't allow blank strings anyway.

Answer (score 5):

From the doc [prompt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.prompt)

```
result = window.prompt(text, value);
```

- **result** is a **string** containing the text entered by the user, or the
  value **null**.
- **text** is a string of text to display to the user. This    parameter is
  optional and can be omitted if there is nothing to show    in the
  prompt window.
- **value** is a string containing the default value displayed in the text
  input field. It is an optional parameter. Note that in Internet
  Explorer 7 and 8, if you do not provide this parameter, the string
  "undefined" is the default value.

The return value is a **string** or **null**. In your example regardless user input, `y` always be a **string** or **object**.

In your case if you want to filter if user enter non-letters you can use a regular expression like:

```js
var x = prompt("Enter a string of letters");

if (!/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(x) || !x) {
  alert("You did not enter a string");
}
```

Comment: @Andyrc if you find this answer useful please mark it as correct.

Comment: You say *`y` will always be a **string** or **object** (null)*. `null` is *not* an object.

Comment: @alex you are right but `typeof(null)` returns object. So in OP `y` always be either a string or object.

Answer (score 2):

Try 
`isNaN(Number(x))`
to check it.

```
var x=prompt("Enter a string");
if(!isNaN(Number(x)){
   alert("You are entering a number!"); 
}
```

Comment: This let's me type `Infinity` too.

Comment: @alex it's easy to filter out. And consider Infinity is possibly a number in the P.O's context... :)

Answer (score 2):

The value returned by `prompt()` is either a string or `null` if the user cancelled.

What you probably want to confirm is the input is alphabetical. You can do that with a regex, such as `^[a-z]+$`

Answer (score -2):

Try this code:

```
x = prompt("Enter a string of letters");

if (/^[a-z]+$/.test(x) {

  alert("You did not enter a string");

}
```

type of x will be string or null even if you enter a number.

Comment: There are a couple of issues with this post. The `if` statement doesn't have a close parenthesis, so the code won't run at all. Either way, it produces the incorrect result: your regex tests that `x` contains only letters. Then, if that's true, you alert that `x` is not a string. Your condition is reversed.

Comment: Also, the user did enter a string. It's *your* job as the programmer to determine if that string should be treated as a number.